# Conda gives unexpected error while creating environment from .yml file

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, virtualenv

`name: Python3.6` 
`dependencies:`  
`- python=3.6`
`- os`
`- conda-forge::numpy`
`- conda-forge::opencv`
`- conda-forge::matplotlib`
`- conda-forge::pillow`
`- conda-forge::ipython`
`- pytorch pytorch-cuda`
`- conda-forge::tqdm`
`- pip`
`- pip:`

> `- torchvision`
> `- torchutils`

I must mention this is the first time I'm doing this.

I checked the spacing for `.yaml` file and it is correct.

I tried:

`conda env  create -n python36  --file py36.yml`,

`CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda env create -n python36  -f py36.yml`,
This gives *'CONDA_NO_PLUGINS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

`conda env create -n python36 -f py36.yml`
I also checked the .`yaml` encoding.